# Идея расширения для браузера

Tags: google-chrome, html, javascript, css

Я занимаюсь версткой, было бы интересно узнать, есть ли расширения для любого браузера с подобным функционалом: когда мы делаем отладку html/css в панели инструментов, то плагин берет на локальном сервере (заранее, конечно же, надо настроить плагин на нужный домен, опять же локальный) нужный нам файл с любым расширением и сохраняет изменения?
Лишнее время уходит на поиск строк и замены =(
Спасибо.
P.S. Сам этим не занимался, если нет подобного решения, вот, думаю, как-то надо реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для CSS есть http://livestyle.emmet.io/

Comment: Спасибо огромное =)